# Can you use subindices in component names in React/JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just started learning ReactJS, and I'm working on a project of my own, an IP netmask calculator: you  type in an IP address and a netmask (in CIDR format), and it shows you the IP range that this netmask covers.

Obviously, the most important UI element for this is going to be a set of 4 text fields for the user to enter an IP address. Something like:

```
        <SPAN CLASS="etiqueta">IP:</span>
        <span class="ip">
            <INPUT TYPE=number maxlength=3>.<INPUT TYPE=number maxlength=3>.<INPUT TYPE=number maxlength=3>.<INPUT TYPE=number maxlength=3>
        </span>
```

(This isn't real React code, just a HTML prototype I made to design the UI).

My doubt is how to "group" the 4 input fields for the user to type in an IP address, so that I know that they are parts of the same "thing". Can you name components in React or JS like this?

```
<input type=number name="ipFrom[0]">

<input type=number name="ipFrom[1]">

<input type=number name="ipFrom[2]">

<input type=number name="ipFrom[3]">
```

If not, what would be a more elegant way to name these 4 text fields, when they refer to parts of one property?

Comment: Are you planning to use those subincides to do some computation later on, by referencing them or is it about naming?

Comment: @HarshaVenkatram I want to use them later to "group" the value of the 4 fields into one value. There are going to be several groups of 4 text fields in my UI, so it would be good to group the ones that are related to each other with the same names.